# Wami-Recorder not picking up audio the first time

Tags: php, javascript, flash

I have a very strange issue with the Wami-recorder. After allowing the flash file permission to use my microphone, I attempted to record an audioclip.  However most of the time, not all the time, the first attempt at recording passes an empty audio clip to the server.

```
FLASH: Listening...
FLASH: Recording at rate: 22050
FLASH: POST 44 bytes of type audio/x-wav
FLASH: Expected Samples: 27849 Actual Samples: 0
FLASH: Unlistening.
FLASH: POST openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
FLASH: POST progressHandler loaded:7 total: 0
FLASH: POST: completeHandler
```

As opposed to

```
FLASH: Listening...
FLASH: Recording at rate: 22050
FLASH: POST 34860 bytes of type audio/x-wav
FLASH: Expected Samples: 19161 Actual Samples: 17408
FLASH: Unlistening.
FLASH: POST openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
FLASH: POST progressHandler loaded:7 total: 0
FLASH: POST: completeHandler
```

I can't figure out what is causing this as it doesn't seem to be happening to everyone.

Comment: I think the page is not loading and you are calling to record the sound. May be because of that at first time it is sending empty file.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar What do you mean? if you mean the page hasn't finished loading, the entire script is encased in a $(document).ready() function.

Comment: i know this sounds like a very ugly solution but how about you automatically pre-record an empty 1 second audioclip and ignore it, so when a user records his own it is actually recorded?

Comment: @user1916182 haha I have actually tried that, for some reason it runs the command before Wami is initialized, even after putting it inside a setTimeout().

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this problem also. Thankfully, I have finally found a workaround.

I think the problem is this: Chrome has its own mechanisms for managing the user's permission to use the microphone, and these mechanisms depend on the operating system. On windows plus Chrome, this particular mechanism conflicts with the mechanism of the Wami-recorder, with the result that the Wami-recorder's permission request is made useless (even though it is still displayed).

I got it to work by forcing Chrome's permission dialog for access to the microphone. Having allowed access to the microphone, this permission holds for the rest of the browser-website session. I forced the permission dialog by requesting to use the microphone via HTML5, copying code from [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Not all browsers support HTML5 or just the microphone access via HTML5. Moreover, on other browsers, this hack is not necessary. To force the dialog only for Chrome, I placed the code in a conditional which tests for Chrome. Curiously, this actually broke the recorder on Chromium (which, curiously contrary to its counterpart on Chrome, was working). I found some code which distinguishes Chrome from Chromium [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278770/how-do-i-detect-chromium-specifically-vs-chrome).

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * isChrome (WithPDFReader)
 * thanks to Rob W from
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278770/how-do-i-detect-chromium-specifically-vs-chrome
 */
function isChrome()
{
    for (var i=0; i<navigator.plugins.length; i++)
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name == 'Chrome PDF Viewer') return true;
    return false;
}

/* somewhere else: */

/*
 * If on Chrome (not Chromium), force permission request 
 */
if( isChrome() )
{
    var context = new window.webkitAudioContext();
     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {
      var microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
       // microphone -> filter -> destination.
      microphone.connect(filter);
      filter.connect(context.destination);
    }, function(){ /* do something */ });
}

// initialize Wami
 Wami.setup({ ... });
```