# How do I detect Chromium specifically vs. Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent, detection, chromium

Is there a way to detect if a visitor to my site is running [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home) as opposed to [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)? Even basic UA sniffing (which I know is bad practice) would suffice for my particular case, but it appears that Chromium and Chrome [share the same UA string](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) – is that correct? Is there any other way that I can differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome ships with a built-in PDF reader, Chromium doesn't.
You could detect this by using JavaScript:

```js
function isChrome() { // Actually, isWithChromePDFReader
    for (var i=0; i<navigator.plugins.length; i++)
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name == 'Chrome PDF Viewer') return true;
    return false;
}
```

This method is not 100% reliable, because users can copy the PDF reader binary from Chrome to their Chromium directory, see [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/135985).

There's almost no difference between Chromium and Chrome (certainly not in the rendering or JavaScript engine), so why do you want to spot the difference?

Comment: Thanks! I assume you probably mean `navigator.plugins[i].name`? (Shift the `s`. :p)

Comment: It's worth nothing this is only true for the Desktop Version of Chrome.

Comment: Sad, my Chromium 39 for Mac returns "true"!

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Chromium 84 there's a new method called User-Agent Client Hints [reference](https://web.dev/user-agent-client-hints/)

You can check if the userAgentData property exists and look for brand data. It will return an array that looks something like this.

```
[{
    "brand": " Not;A Brand",
    "version": "99"
}, {
    "brand": "Google Chrome",
    "version": "91"
}, {
    "brand": "Chromium",
    "version": "91"
}]
```

userAgentData.brands will contain varying values in a varying order, so don't rely on something appearing at a certain index. Instead check if the property exists in the array.

```
if (navigator.userAgentData) {
    let vendors = window.navigator.userAgentData.brands;
    if (vendors.filter(e => e.brand === 'Google Chrome').length > 0) {
        console.log('Chrome')
    } else {
        console.log('Chromium')
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still working in October 2021.

Answer (score 7):

**Note:**
This no longer works, because **now all Chrome-based-navigators have all plugins**.

New Chromium-versions do have the PDF-plugin, too. 
But they also have Chromium-plugins, so if any plugin starts with "Chromium", it's Chromium:

```js
function isChromium() {

  for (var i = 0, u = "Chromium", l = u.length; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) {
    if (navigator.plugins[i].name != null && navigator.plugins[i].name.substr(0, l) === u)
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Also, use this to identify Microsoft Chredge (aka. Anaheim)

```js
function isEdg() {

  for (var i = 0, u = "Microsoft Edg", l = u.length; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) {
    if (navigator.plugins[i].name != null && navigator.plugins[i].name.substr(0, l) === u)
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation to Paul W.'s answer that works for Chromium version 42 and above:

```
function isChromium() { // Actually, isWithChromiumPDFReader
    for (var i=0; i<navigator.plugins.length; i++)
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name == 'Chromium PDF Viewer') return true;
    return false;
}
```

This of course only works if the plugin has not been disabled by the user.

Comment: This didn't work with me on Chrome `94.0.4606.81`. It returned `true` while it was Chrome, NOT Chromium!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, using `SpeechSynthesis` feature.

Google Chrome Browser ships TTS voices, where Chromium browsers (incl. Brave) do not. Voices can be installed manually, with `espeak` (on linux) however the *Google voices* all start with `Google`, where the manually installed voices do not. As far as I know the Chrome voices are propriety, not free.

The collection of voices is an Array where each voices looks like this:

```json
{
    voiceURI: "Google Deutsch",
    name: "Google Deutsch",
    lang: "de-DE",
    localService: false,
    default: true
}
```

We just need to find one who's name/URI starts with **Google ...**

```js
function hasGoogleVoices() {
    return window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()
      .some(v => /^google/i.test(v.name));
}
```

(Tested on Linux for Chrome, Brave, Chromium and Firefox)
Please can someone check Safari and Windows. Thx.

Comment: Tested on Chrome 94 on Windows 7 in 2021/10. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Could not comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428992/14238203 Josh Answer.

On latest Chrome and Chromium (Oct 2021) some of the solutions returns true for both, so I had to find a different solution.

I took https://stackoverflow.com/a/63724166/14238203 fliptopbox code and implmented Josh answer.

`const isChrome = navigator.userAgentData.brands.some((v) => /^google/i.test(v.brand));`

The issue with Josh answer is that if you try this when just loading a page, the getVoices() returns empty array until all the voices are loaded (page finished loading)
A promise solution to that here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786665/14238203

For my use case it was a bit cumbersome with the getVoices() so I used the user agent hints solution.

Answer (score 0):

After searching this was how I was able to make it work. You can use the navigator.userAgentData.brands[0].brand to fetch the Brand that a user's browser is. Because this object is not supported on all browsers (and older Google Chrome versions) you may need to wrap it in a try catch to prevent an unhandled exception error.

```
if (userAgent.includes("Chrome")) {
  try {
    const userBrand = navigator.userAgentData.brands[0].brand;

    if (userBrand === 'Google Chrome') {
      // User is 100% using Google Chrome
    } else {
      // User is maybe using an older
      // version of Google Chrome released in 2021 without support for the 
      //userAgentData or they're using a Chromium browser
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Since the navigator.userAgentData.brands doesn't exist
    // We need to handle the error. If it doesn't exist, the user is not using 
    //Google Chrome or once again is using an older version of Google Chrome
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way that does not rely on the deprecated `navigator.plugins` API.

Disclaimer: it is not 100% guaranteed to work when someone uses customized Chromium with added codecs.

Disclaimer 2: it's still better to use a UserAgent-based method. In my particular use-case I couldn't rely on user agent.

```js
const video = document.createElement('video') // Create a video element
const canPlayH264 =  video.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"') // Verify h264 support

if (canPlayH264 === 'probably') {
  console.log('Only Chrome can play h264')
} else {
  console.log('Plain Chromium cannot play h264')
}
```