# Getting the list of voices in speechSynthesis (Web Speech API)

Tags: dom-events, voice, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

Following HTML shows empty array in console on first click:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test(){
                console.log(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices())
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="test()">Test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

In second click you will get the expected list.

If you add `onload` event to call this function (`<body onload="test()">`), then you can get correct result on first click. Note that the first call on `onload` still doesn't work properly. It returns empty on page load but works afterward.

**Questions:**

Since it might be [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340160) in beta version, I gave up on "Why" questions.

Now, the question is if you want to access `window.speechSynthesis` on page load:

- What is the best hack for this issue?
- How can you make sure it will load `speechSynthesis`, on page load?

**Background and tests:**

I was testing the new features in Web Speech API, then I got to this problem in my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Browser support messages. (You might need Chrome 33.0 Beta)
    if (!('speechSynthesis' in window)) {
      alert("You don't have speechSynthesis");
    }

    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    console.log(voices) // []

    $("#test").on('click', function(){
        var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        console.log(voices); // [SpeechSynthesisVoice, ...]
    });
});
</script>
<a id="test" href="#">click here if 'ready()' didn't work</a>
```

My question was: why does `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` return empty array, after page is loaded and `onready` function is triggered? As you can see if you click on the link, same function returns an array of available voices of Chrome by `onclick` triger?

It seems Chrome loads `window.speechSynthesis` after the page load!

The problem is not in `ready` event. If I remove the line `var voice=...` from `ready` function, for first click it shows empty list in console. But the second click works fine.

It seems `window.speechSynthesis` needs more time to load after first call. You need to call it twice! But also, you need to wait and let it load before second call on `window.speechSynthesis`. For example, following code shows two empty arrays in console if you run it for first time:

```
// First speechSynthesis call
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
console.log(voices);

// Second speechSynthesis call
voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
console.log(voices);
```

Comment: hmmm, just a guess, but do you have have the html attribute tags related to speech synthesis on your page by default? If not, it might be taking chrome a bit of time to work that part out by itself.

Comment: no other speech attributes are there. I have another update to my question. Maybe the problem is not with `ready`.

Comment: In Dart, I called `getVoices()` after 5 seconds delay using `Timer` and got a populated list of available voices.

Comment: @Mehdi. You should write an answer with some of your edits above. Calling `getVoices()` twice with one second delay solves the issue.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

According to [Web Speech API Errata](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi-errata.html) (E11 2013-10-17), the voice list is loaded async to the page. An `onvoiceschanged` event is fired when they are loaded.

> voiceschanged: Fired when the contents of the SpeechSynthesisVoiceList, that the getVoices method will return, have changed. Examples include: server-side synthesis where the list is determined asynchronously, or when client-side voices are installed/uninstalled.

So, the trick is to set your voice from the callback for that event listener:

```
// wait on voices to be loaded before fetching list
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
    window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    ...
};
```

Comment: That was a bad decision. The voice will be weird until loaded (French).

Comment: The voices are loaded asynchronously, but are they all loaded at the same time or is the `onvoiceschanged` event fired more than once?

Comment: Also, do you have to call `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` and then wait for `onvoiceschanged` to fire or does the event fire every time sometime during or after page load?

Comment: @DouglasDeRizzoMeneghetti - Testing against Chrome, I don't find onvoiceschanged callback called until I perform some Speech work such as making a call to getVoices() in the first place.

Comment: @Kolban My solution involved calling `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` when the page loaded and trying to get the voice I wanted in the `onvoiceschanged` event, as well as every time I were to synthesize something as well, until I could get the voice I wanted and assign it to a variable. Also, in case I couldn't get the voice in time for the synthesis, setting the utterance `lang` property to the one corresponding to the language I wanted (`pt-BR` in my case) would do the trick in some platforms.

Comment: For some reason in my case (chrome) the onvoiceschanged event is fired three times even if it seems all the voices are ready the first time. The result is that I heard the same sentence three times. My workaraound:
exit = 0;
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices(); 
    if (exit == 0){ var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(msg);
        utterThis.voice = voices[10];
        synth.speak(utterThis);
        exit = 1;
    }
}

Comment: Incomplete answer.

Comment: @DouglasDeRizzoMeneghetti `onvoiceschanged` will fire automatically when the page loads. You do not have to call `getVoices` first.

Comment: Turns out Firefox will make the voices already available when the page is reloaded/from same process. They thus won't fire that event and make the voices already available. So there you actually need the call to `getVoices()` in order to not wait that event that will never happen again. So `if( getVoices().length ) { callback(); } else { onvoiceschanged = callback; }`

Answer (score 10):

After studying the behavior on Google Chrome and Firefox, this is what can get all voices:

Since it involves something asynchronous, it might be best done with a promise:

```js
const allVoicesObtained = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  let voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  if (voices.length !== 0) {
    resolve(voices);
  } else {
    window.speechSynthesis.addEventListener("voiceschanged", function() {
      voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      resolve(voices);
    });
  }
});

allVoicesObtained.then(voices => console.log("All voices:", voices));
```

Note:

1. When the event `voiceschanged` fires, we need to call `.getVoices()` again. The original array won't be populated with content.
2. On Google Chrome, we don't have to call `getVoices()` initially. We only need to listen on the event, and *it will then happen*. On Firefox, listening is not enough, you have to call `getVoices()` and then listen on the event `voiceschanged`, and set the array using `getVoices()` once you get notified.
3. Using a promise makes the code more clean. Everything related to getting voices are in this promise code. If you don't use a promise but instead put this code in your speech routine, it is quite messy.
4. You can write a `voiceObtained` promise to resolve to a voice you want, and then your function to say something can just do:  `voiceObtained.then(voice => { })` and inside that handler, call the `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` to speak something. Or you can even write a promise `speechReady("hello world").then(speech => { window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech) })` to say something.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a setInterval to wait until the voices are loaded before using them however you need and then clearing the setInterval:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    console.log(voices);
    if (voices.length !== 0) {
      var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(/*some string here*/);
      msg.voice = voices[/*some number here to choose from array*/];
      speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 200);

$("#test").on('click', timer);
```

Comment: Timer is better option for me as onvoiceschanged appears to not be supported on safari.

Comment: listen on an event is better... we don't want to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to keep pinging it ... unless if there is no other method

Comment: @Thibs `voiceschanged` event works in Safari now, idk when it was added

Answer (score 5):

heres the answer

```
function synthVoice(text) {

  const awaitVoices = new Promise(resolve=> 
    window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = resolve)  
  .then(()=> {
    const synth = window.speechSynthesis;

    var voices = synth.getVoices();
    console.log(voices)

    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utterance.voice = voices[3];        
    utterance.text = text;

    synth.speak(utterance);
  });
}
```

Comment: Have synthesis working in one chrome tab.  Tried this in another chrome tab.  Yes, I appended synthVoice("Hello world!"), but no sound was heard.

Answer (score 3):

At first i used onvoiceschanged , but it kept firing even after the voices was loaded, so my goal was to avoid onvoiceschanged at all cost.

This is what i came up with.  It seems to work so far, will update if it breaks.

```
loadVoicesWhenAvailable();

function loadVoicesWhenAvailable() {
         voices = synth.getVoices();

         if (voices.length !== 0) {
                console.log("start loading voices");
                LoadVoices();
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(function () { loadVoicesWhenAvailable(); }, 10)
            }
    }
```

Comment: what does `LoadVoices()` refer to?

Answer (score 2):

**setInterval solution by Salman Oskooi was perfect**

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/exrx8e1y/

```
function myFunction() {

  dtlarea=document.getElementById("details");
  //dtlarea.style.display="none";
  dtltxt="";

  var mytimer = setInterval(function() {

      var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      //console.log(voices);
      if (voices.length !== 0) {

        var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

        msg.rate = document.getElementById("rate").value; // 0.1 to 10
        msg.pitch = document.getElementById("pitch").value; //0 to 2
        msg.volume = document.getElementById("volume").value; // 0 to 1

        msg.text = document.getElementById("sampletext").value; 
        msg.lang =  document.getElementById("lang").value; //'hi-IN';

        for(var i=0;i<voices.length;i++){

            dtltxt+=voices[i].lang+' '+voices[i].name+'\n';

            if(voices[i].lang==msg.lang) {
              msg.voice = voices[i]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params
              msg.voiceURI = voices[i].voiceURI;
              // break;
            }
        }

        msg.onend = function(e) {
          console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
          dtlarea.value=dtltxt; 
        };

        speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

        clearInterval(mytimer);

      }
  }, 1000);

}
```

This works fine on Chrome for MAC, Linux(Ubuntu), Windows and Android

Android has non-standard en_GB wile others have en-GB as language code
Also you will see that same language(lang) has multiple names

On Mac Chrome you get en-GB Daniel besides en-GB Google UK English Female and n-GB Google UK English Male

en-GB Daniel (Mac and iOS)
en-GB Google UK English Female
en-GB Google UK English Male
en_GB English United Kingdom
hi-IN Google हिन्दी
hi-IN Lekha (Mac and iOS)
hi_IN Hindi India

Answer (score 1):

Another way to ensure voices are loaded before you need them is to bind their loading state to a promise, and then dispatch your speech commands from a `then`:

```
const awaitVoices = new Promise(done => speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = done);

function listVoices() {
    awaitVoices.then(()=> {
        let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        console.log(voices);
    });
}
```

When you call `listVoices`, it will either wait for the voices to load first, or dispatch your operation on the next tick.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, console.log(voices) is never executed

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to load voices successfully:

```
<select id="voices"></select>
```

...

```
  function loadVoices() {
    populateVoiceList();
    if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
      speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = populateVoiceList;
    }
  }

  function populateVoiceList() {
    var allVoices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    allVoices.forEach(function(voice, index) {
      var option = $('<option>').val(index).html(voice.name).prop("selected", voice.default);
      $('#voices').append(option);
    });
    if (allVoices.length > 0 && speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
      // unregister event listener (it is fired multiple times)
      speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = null;
    }
  }
```

I found the 'onvoiceschanged' code from this article: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/01/firefox-and-the-web-speech-api/

Note: requires JQuery.

Works in Firefox/Safari and Chrome (and in Google Apps Script too - but only in the HTML).

Answer (score 1):

```
async function speak(txt) {
    await initVoices();
    const u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(txt);
    u.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()[3];
    speechSynthesis.speak(u);
}

function initVoices() {
  return new Promise(function (res, rej){
    speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    if (window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged) {
       res();
    } else {
      window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => res();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer works great but if you're using SPA and not loading full-page, on navigating between links, the voices will not be available.

This will run on a full-page load

```
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged
```

For SPA, it wouldn't run.

You can check if it's undefined, run it, or else, get it from the window object.

An example that works:

```
let voices = [];
if(window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged == undefined){
     window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {
     voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
   }
 }else{
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
 }
 // console.log("voices", voices);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    let gotVoices = false;
    if (voices.length) {
        resolve(voices, message);
    } else {
        speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {
            if (!gotVoices) {
                voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
                gotVoices = true;
                if (voices.length) resolve(voices, message);
            }
        };
    }
```

```
function resolve(voices, message) {
    var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
    let utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utter.lang = 'en-US';
    utter.voice = voices[65];
    utter.text = message;
    utter.volume = 100.0;
    synth.speak(utter);
}
```

Works for Edge, Chrome and Safari - doesn't repeat the sentences.

Comment: Works for me using react js. Edge

Answer (score 0):

I had to do my own research for this to make sure I understood it properly, so just sharing (feel free to edit).

My goal is to:

- Get a list of voices available on my device
- Populate a select element with those voices (after a particular page loads)
- Use easy to understand code

The basic functionality is demonstrated in MDN's [official live demo](https://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speak-easy-synthesis) of:

https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api/tree/master/speak-easy-synthesis

but I wanted to understand it better.

To break the topic down...

**SpeechSynthesis**

> The `SpeechSynthesis` interface of the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) is the controller
>   interface for the speech service; this can be used to retrieve
>   information about the synthesis voices available on the device, start
>   and pause speech, and other commands besides.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis)

**onvoiceschanged**

> The `onvoiceschanged` property of the `SpeechSynthesis` interface
>   represents an event handler that will run when the list of
>   `SpeechSynthesisVoice` objects that would be returned by the
>   `SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()` method has changed (when the `voiceschanged`
>   event fires.)

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/onvoiceschanged)

**Example A**

If my application merely has:

```
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
console.log(synth);
console.log(synth.onvoiceschanged);
```

Chrome developer tools console will show:

[image]

**Example B**

If I change the code to:

```
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;

console.log("BEFORE");
console.log(synth);
console.log(synth.onvoiceschanged);

console.log("AFTER");
var voices = synth.getVoices();

console.log(voices);
console.log(synth);
console.log(synth.onvoiceschanged);
```

The before and after states are the same, and `voices` is an empty array.

[image]

**Solution**

Although i'm not confident implementing [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), the following worked for me:

*Defining the function*

```
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
// declare so that values are accessible globally
var voices = [];


function set_up_speech() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        // get the voices
        var voices = synth.getVoices();

        // get reference to select element
        var $select_topic_speaking_voice = $("#select_topic_speaking_voice");

        // for each voice, generate select option html and append to select
        for (var i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {

            var option = $("<option></option>");

            var suffix = "";

            // if it is the default voice, add suffix text  
            if (voices[i].default) {
                suffix = " -- DEFAULT";
            }

            // create the option text
            var option_text = voices[i].name + " (" + voices[i].lang + suffix + ")";

            // add the option text
            option.text(option_text);

            // add option attributes
            option.attr("data-lang", voices[i].lang);
            option.attr("data-name", voices[i].name);

            // append option to select element
            $select_topic_speaking_voice.append(option);
        }

        // resolve the voices value
        resolve(voices)

    });

}
```

*Calling the function*

```
// in your handler, populate the select element    
if (page_title === "something") {
set_up_speech()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Chrome - turn off data saver. It was helpfull for me.(Chrome 71.0.3578.99)

```
// wait until the voices load
   window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
    window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();

};
```