# Chrome speech synthesis api not changing options

Tags: javascript, prototype, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to change the an instance of the speech synthesis API's options (such as pitch, volume etc) but its not working. For some reason, the only way I can get it to change the voice from UK male to UK female is to call the var voices variable twice, but this is the only  option I can change in this. Here is the code:

```
//After the document loads (using the prototype library)
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    //When the speakMe button is clicked
    $("speakMe").observe('click', function() {
        //Get the entered phrase
        phrase = $('phraseBar').getValue();
        //If the phrase is blank
        if(phrase =="")
        {
            //Warning message
            alert("Please enter a phrase before asking me to speak for you. Thank you!");
        }
        else
        {
            //Declare the speach object & set attributes
            var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(phrase);
            var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
            var options = new Object();
            speech.default = false;
            speech.localservice = true;
            speech.voice = voices.filter(function(voice) { return voice.name == userVoice; })[0];    
            speech.lang = userLang;
            speech.rate = userRate;
            speech.pitch = 2;
            speech.volume = userVolume;

            //Speak the phrase
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);

        }
    });
    var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Chrome known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376280) with the rate, volume, or pitch options not having an effect for some voices.

Also, the reason why `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` is working the second time is that it in Chrome it should be called after the `onvoiceschanged` event (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22978802/1873374)).