# javascript speech.synthesis.speak properties

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, speech-synthesis

I have searched and searched to no avail. There is no clear documentation for this API at least from wht ive found. I want to make a custom object that can hold the properties for this function and be able to run it

```js
console.log(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices());
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
var kline = new Object();

kline.speakAloud = function(message) {
 Speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(message);
 Speech.voice = voices[2];
 Speech.gender = "male";
 Speech.voiceURI = "Google UK English Male";
 Speech.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
 Speech.rate = 1; // 0.1 to 10
 Speech.pitch = 2; //0 to 2
 Speech.lang = 'en-GB';
 window.speechSynthesis.speak(Speech);  
};
kline.speakText = function(message) {
 document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = message;
};
 
 
 //Arrays for Algorithmic Input Processing 
 
 var Greetings = ["hello", "hey", "hi", "sup"];
 var Functions = ["say", "search", "math", "", "", "", "", ""];


function Run() {
 message = document.getElementById("Input").value.toLowerCase();
 console.log("Successfully ran function" + '\n' + "Input:" + document.getElementById("Input").value + '\n' + "Proccesed input:" + message);
 
 //If statement 
 if (message === ("hello")) { // greating
  kline.speakAloud("testing");
  kline.speakText("testing");
 }
 else if (message === ("X")) { //
  kline.speakAloud("");
  kline.speakText(""); 
 }
 else if (message === ("X")) { //
  kline.speakAloud("");
  kline.speakText(""); 
 }
 else if (message === ("X")) { //
  kline.speakAloud("");
  kline.speakText(""); 
 }
}
```

If you need to html i can post this as well, its basically a input box and a button to call Run(). The code works but I can not get it to be a male voice. I would like to keep in contained in this same object with a way to call it using methods, if anybody has a way to make it sound male or knows the documentation of this please post this as i hope other people searching for documentation will find your lovely answer.

Im also running linux 15 and chrome version 48. I would like if possible the ability to run this on other browsers. lets take baby steps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most complete documentation is in the [Web Speech API Specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html).

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22978802/1873374), the voices array is only loaded after the `window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged` event has fired. If you move your initialization code to this event then the voices will be available.

```js
var voices = []
var kline = new Object();

window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    console.log(voices);
    
    kline.speakAloud = function(message) {
    Speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(message);
    Speech.voice = voices[2];
    Speech.voiceURI = "Google UK English Male";
    Speech.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
    Speech.rate = 1; // 0.1 to 10
    Speech.pitch = 0; //0 to 2
    Speech.lang = 'en-GB';
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(Speech);  
  };
  kline.speakText = function(message) {
    document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = message;
  };
  
};
 
 //Arrays for Algorithmic Input Processing 
 
 var Greetings = ["hello", "hey", "hi", "sup"];
 var Functions = ["say", "search", "math", "", "", "", "", ""];


function Run() {
 message = document.getElementById("Input").value.toLowerCase();
 console.log("Successfully ran function" + '\n' + "Input:" + document.getElementById("Input").value + '\n' + "Proccesed input:" + message);
 
 //If statement 
 if (message === ("hello")) { // greating
  kline.speakAloud("testing");
  kline.speakText("testing");
 }
 else if (message === ("X")) { //
  kline.speakAloud("");
  kline.speakText(""); 
 }
 else if (message === ("X")) { //
  kline.speakAloud("");
  kline.speakText(""); 
 }
 else if (message === ("X")) { //
  kline.speakAloud("");
  kline.speakText(""); 
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Input" value="hello"/>
<input type="text" id="Output"/>
<button id="run" onclick="Run()">
Run
</button>
```

Comment: I put this into my program, as u made it much more organized but its still not speaking in a male voice, let me know if it is for you cause I've heard there are problems with certain OS.

Comment: Make sure that voices[2] is the one you want. On my system Google UK English Male is voices[4].

Comment: what OS do you have(windows, Linux, Mac, etc.) cause i changed it to 4 and its still a female voice. no different from what i had when i used my original code.

Comment: Use the developer tools to look at the voices array in the console. It is different in each OS and browser.