# How can I get female voice by Web Speech API in Google Chrome

Tags: web, speech-synthesis

In a webpage, I want a female voice to speak my texts. I tried to do this by following code. But still now male voice is talking. How can I arrange a female voice to talk my texts? Can anybody share me a correct code that works in Google Chrome.

```
var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello World!");
msg.default=false; 
msg.localservice=true;
msg.lang = "en-GB";
msg.voice = voices[3].name;
speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of troubleshooting, I could figure out the solution.

4 persons already suggested me some solutions. But these did not work for me. But helped me to figure out the solution. Thanks to all of them.

To solve the problem, I did two things.

1. I had to load voices during onvoiceschanged event as follows:

   ```
   var voices;    
   window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
       voices=window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
   };
   ```

I found this tip from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513706/getting-the-list-of-voices-in-speechsynthesis-of-chrome-web-speech-api).

2. 'Google UK English Female' does not work for me. So I used 'Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)' as follows:

   ```
   speech.voice = voices.filter(function(voice) { return voice.name == 'Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)'; })[0];
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The below code worked for me. I hope it works for you.

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
msg.voice = voices[3];
msg.text = "Hello World";
speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

On the 1st try it might give out male's voice. But on the 2nd attempt (without refreshing) it will give out the female's voice and try deploying it on a dummy server, there it will work like a charm in the first go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877555/female-voice-in-google-chrome-speechsynthesis , Some thing weird I came across.

Comment: That depends on the listed voices. You are just accessing a hardcoded property and if voicelist change because of whatever reason, you get a different voice.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me that the voice doesn't change at the first time the page is loaded.

I found a solution that works for me.
**getVoices()**  should be triggered when the document is ready.
So I add at the top of my js like this.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome, I do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function speak(language, country, preferredNames, text) {
        var resolvePromise;
        var promise = new Promise(r => resolvePromise = r);

        var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        if (voices.length == 0) {
            new Promise(r => {
                window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => { 
                        window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = null;
                        r(); 
                    };
            })
            .then(() => speak(language, country, preferredNames, text))
            .then(resolvePromise);
        } else {
            var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
            voices.sort((a, b) => {
                if (language != null) {
                    var matchA = a.lang.indexOf(language + "-") == 0;
                    var matchB = b.lang.indexOf(language + "-") == 0;
                    if (! matchA && ! matchB) return 0;
                    if (! matchA && matchB) return 1;
                    if (! matchB && matchA) return -1;
                }
                if (country != null) {
                    var matchA = a.lang.indexOf("-" + country) == a.lang.length - ("-" + country).length;
                    var matchB = b.lang.indexOf("-" + country) == b.lang.length - ("-" + country).length;
                    if (! matchA && ! matchB) return 0;
                    if (! matchA && matchB) return 1;
                    if (! matchB && matchA) return -1;
                }
                if (preferredNames != null) {
                    var indexA = voices.length;
                    var indexB = voices.length;
                    preferredNames.forEach((e, i) => {
                        if (indexA == voices.length && a.name.match(e) != null) indexA = i; 
                        if (indexB == voices.length && b.name.match(e) != null) indexB = i; 
                    });
                    return indexA - indexB;
                }
                return 0;
            });
            if (voices.length > 0) msg.voice = voices[0];
            if (language != null) {
                msg.lang = language;
                if (country != null) msg.lang += "-" + country;
            }
            msg.onend = resolvePromise;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

            // msg.onend not triggered without call to console.log(msg)?
            console.log(msg);
        }

        return promise;
    }

    speak("en", null, [ /Google US English/, /Samantha/, /Fiona/, /Victoria/, /female/i ], "Hello, world.")
    .then(() => speak("en", null, [ /female/i ], "Hello, world."))
    .then(() => speak("en", "US", [ /female/i ], "Hello, world."))
    .then(() => speak("en", "US", null, "Hello, world."))
    .then(() => speak("en", "GB", [ /\Wmale/i ], "Hello, world."));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me.

```
  var speakObj = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  speakObj.text = text;
  speakObj.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) {
    return voice.name == "Google UK English Female"

  })[0];
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(speakObj);
```