# Female voice in google chrome speechSynthesis

Tags: google-chrome, speech-synthesis

Im using this exact code in both the scenarios.

```
        var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        msg.voice = voices[1];
        msg.text = "hello world";
        msg.lang = 'en-US';
        speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

If I run this in the chrome console I get a female voice. But if I put the exact code in an index.html and run it, it plays a male voice. Could any one please clarify why this difference occurs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the Root cause.
[Getting the list of voices in speechSynthesis of Chrome (Web Speech API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513706/getting-the-list-of-voices-in-speechsynthesis-of-chrome-web-speech-api)

The calls are async, so when I try to run in index.html the voices array is empty. As I suggested when I run this and then use the speak it works fine.

```
    var msg;
    var voices;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        console.log(voices);
        if (voices.length !== 0) {
            msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            msg.voice = voices[0];
            speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
            msg.lang = 'en-US';
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 200);
    timer();
    speechSynthesis.speak("hello world");
```

Comment: this works fine!!! just adding the index of whatever the voice we want will change the voice type. eg: msg.voice = voices[1]; will change to female voice of "Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)"