# Can I select voice in browser speech when using WebChat

Tags: botframework

All the custom voice samples are about cognitive service speech.
But I want to use the browser speech and I want to select a female voice.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#enable-speech-services?

Comment: @ranusharao I have already enabled browser speech. Just need a way to change the voice to a female voice.

Comment: not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215361/how-can-i-get-female-voice-by-web-speech-api-in-google-chrome helps.