# offline use of Web Speech API html5 doesnt recognize choosen accent voice

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech

My native language is spanish, so my laptop is set in spanish....

the problem is that Im using my local server (localhost) to learn german and Ive set up some javacript code to speak out loud some words in german

```
         var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("der Hund");
        msg.lang = 'de-DE';
        msg.rate = 0.6;
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

It works pretty well (when online It speak out loud in german with german accent as set in the code)...until I go offline (without internet)...once that happens...the voice speaks out loud the same word as well `der Hund` but now with spanish accent...

So I would like to know...what should I do to make the API work correctly online and offline.

Comment: Please add which languages this is coded in? The code sample you show is more than just HTML. Thank you

Comment: Did you write this code from scratch or did you use a base javascript library to speak the language?

Comment: Have you set your HTML page to be `<html lang='DE-de'>`?

Comment: @Martin good observation......I have this only tag `<meta name="language" content="de" />` is that correct? or do I need to ad to the html tag as well?

Comment: In HTML5 the `lang` tag in the `<html>` element should be set.

Comment: [read this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations.es) `;-)`

Comment: @Martin it make sense, but still not working :/

Comment: Ok then the issue is your Javascript -- as asked above; what javascript library do you use to speak the language?

Comment: the API. `SpeechSynthesisUtterance()`

Comment: Also, according to [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/lang) you should be setting a `synth.getVoices` value as well, but I don't see that in your code....

Comment: I  commented `/msg.lang = 'de-DE';` with `<html lang='de-DE'>` and not working

Comment: I suspect you have to set the `accent` in the `synth.getVoices` object.....?

Comment: I dont actually understand how touse that function

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694586/how-to-change-voice-in-speech-synthesis) or otherwise find an online tutorial and / or guide as to how to use this technology.

Comment: good link thanks. Im supossed to use `msg.voice = "Google Deutsch";` but the script stops working...I think that here is the answer https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/wGzuJ

Comment: Good luck with it

Comment: Ok I added the line `var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
msg.voice = voices[6];` it selects the german voice...works online but not offline....such a frustration

Comment: What os are you on? Do you have a voice on your system in this language? If not, you need to install one, at the OS level.

Comment: @Kaiido I have windows 8. How should I install this german voice?

Comment: I guess [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-voices-for-immersive-reader-read-mode-and-read-aloud-4c83a8d8-7486-42f7-8e46-2b0fdf753130) is what you want, though I don't have a windows 8 at hand to try. And [for win10](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-download-text-to-speech-languages-for-windows-10-d5a6b612-b3ae-423f-afa5-4f6caf1ec5d3)