# Web Speech API reads in wrong language in Safari

Tags: javascript, html

i have tried to make a text to speech on my web page with the Web Speech API. The problem is when the code is being run in Safari (tested only in chrome,edge and safari yet) it is not being read in the language needed i think because the voice list changes in Safari and could not fix it, I need it to be in Turkish language.

```
 <button id="cancelBtn" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs rounded" style="padding: 4px 7px; margin-top: 15px;">Okumayi durdur</button>
                <button id="speakBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs rounded pull-right" style="padding: 4px 7px; margin-top: 15px;">Haberi Oku <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i></button>


                    <?php
                    $pt=$row['postdetails'];
                    echo  (substr($pt,0));?>


                <script>
                    window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged;
                    function textToSpeech() {
                        //alert("Test"); //for test only.
                        const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
                        let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
                        let convert = document.getElementById("textID").innerHTML;

                        speech.text = convert;
                        speech.volume = 1;
                        speech.rate = 1;
                        speech.pitch = 1;
                        speech.voice = voices[3];
                        console.log(voices[3]);
                        speechSynthesis.speak(speech);

                    }


                    //function pause() {
                    //    window.speechSynthesis.pause();
                    //}


                    function stop() {
                        window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
                    }

                    speakBtn.addEventListener('click', textToSpeech);
                    //pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pause);
                    cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', stop);
                </script>
```

Comment: Really dumb idea here but you could have a counter variable and then if the counter is 0 then don't speak and run the function again, I ran into the same problem with loading all the languages available

Comment: @DaMahdi03 that's not a good idea -- better to use `window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged` as described in the dupe: [Getting the list of voices in speechSynthesis (Web Speech API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513706/getting-the-list-of-voices-in-speechsynthesis-web-speech-api)