# How to set Speech Synthesis to a specific voice without overlapping with the default voice

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am currently trying to set a specific voice in `speechSynthesis` and I did it but the issue I am facing now is that whenever I trigger the voice, in my case I use a button, the first time I click the button, it triggers the voice from the `lang` that I put there which is `en-GB`, and the chosen voice will only effect on second click onwards. I want only 1 voice to work which is the one I chose from `getVoices`.You can try the code down below to see what I mean, thank you!

```js
function speakTTS() {
  const voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  const message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  message.text = "Please get me a bottle of water, thank you.";
  message.volume = 1; // Volume range = 0 - 1
  message.rate = 1.1; // Speed of the text read , default 1
  message.voice = voices[9]; // change voice
  message.lang = 'en-GB'; // Language, default 'en-US'
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(message);
  console.log(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices());
}
```

```html
<button onClick=speakTTS()>Speak</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an onvoiceschanged event listener that we can use. It will fire
when the voices have completely loaded.

```js
let voices

window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
  voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
};

function speakTTS() {
  const message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  message.text = "Please get me a bottle of water, thank you.";
  message.volume = 1; // Volume range = 0 - 1
  message.rate = 1.1; // Speed of the text read , default 1
  message.voice = voices[9]; // change voice
  message.lang = 'en-GB'; // Language, default 'en-US'
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(message);
  console.log(voices);
}
```

```html
<button onClick=speakTTS()>Speak</button>
```

> The onvoiceschanged property of the SpeechSynthesis interface
> represents an event handler that will run when the list of
> SpeechSynthesisVoice objects that would be returned by the
> SpeechSynthesis.getVoices() method has changed (when the voiceschanged
> event fires.)

[UDN Web Docs: SpeechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged](https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/onvoiceschanged)

Comment: edited thanks to the top answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513706/getting-the-list-of-voices-in-speechsynthesis-web-speech-api