# How are websites able to detect that a browser using Chromium (like Electron) is not Chrome itself?

Tags: javascript, security, electron, frontend

I made an app in Electron (which uses Chromium to render web content) to help perform some tasks on certain sites like SoundCloud.

Here is the `webview` code:

```
<webview partition="persist:default" webpreferences="nodeIntegration=no, contextIsolation=no, enableRemoteModule=yes, worldSafeExecuteJavaScript=yes, webSecurity=yes, allowRunningInsecureContent=no, plugins=yes, scrollBounce=yes, navigateOnDragDrop=yes, safeDialogs=yes, backgroundThrottling=no, nativeWindowOpen=yes, spellcheck=yes" src="https://soundcloud.com/discover" allowpopups=""></webview>
```

I am using the latest version of Electron and have set the user agent of the `webview` to what would normally be Chrome's user agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36`

Here is the result of logging the `navigator` object in the console of the `webview`:

[image]

Here is the result of logging `navigator` on a real Chrome browser on the same computer:

[image]

However, some sites are able to somehow detect that the browser is not really Chrome. For example, when attempting to log in to SoundCloud in the `webview`, it gives an error "Our robots think you are a robot" and this error is not present when logging in on Chrome itself.

[image]

What else could SoundCloud (and other sites) be checking that leads it to believe it is not really a legit version of Chrome? The `navigator` object is all I could think of but it appears to be exactly the same as the `navigator` object in real Chrome. There is no other code being executed in the webview so the site must be checking something before the login.

Comment: What's an "unofficial" browser?

Comment: Electron uses Chromium to render web content. So by unofficial I mean any browser that uses Chromium that isn't Chrome itself. Changed the title to be more clear.

Comment: Probably a related question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278770/